# Copy constructor

Tags: c++

In class of this design:

```
class X
{
    X* left_;
    X* right_;
    X(const X&)
};
```

when trying to implement cpy ctor I'm getting into loop:

```
X::X(const X& pattern)
{
    if (this != &pattern)
    {
        left_ = new X(*pattern.left_);//this is the line
    }
}
```

As a solution to that I'm thinking of using memcpy + operator new() fnc, but is there better way to do it?

Comment: Excuse-me, but how can `this` ever equal `&pattern`?  AFAIK, they're two different objects!

Comment: Why not? See code:
X x;
X::X(x);

Comment: @Ajay: you can't call constructors explicitly like that. In a copy constructor, the argument cannot be `this`, since the object being constructed did not exist when the argument was formed.

Comment: @Ajay: What is that supposed to be?  That's not C++.

Comment: @Mike you're right this will not be possible. I've made mistake. This construct should be used with assignment optor;

Comment: Speed-post! My point was to prove that it is possible that both 'this' and address-of argument in CCTOR can be same. `x.XX::XX(x);` achieves the same. It is perfectly valid in C++.

Comment: Is compiles on VC2008. Where it doesn't compile?

Comment: @Ajay: XX is not a function of XX.  If you are thinking that's the name of the constructor, you are wrong, constructors do not have names, and as such, cannot be directly called, or referred to.

Comment: If it is not valid, how STL classes would be able to call default, copy constructors and the destructor?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I used XX class in my code having XX constructor and XX copy-ctor.
All complainers - why don't you try and tell everyone if it compiles on your compiler on not - rather than going by some "text"

Comment: @Ajay: http://ideone.com/EDM7L try it out here to http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/

Comment: @Ajay: Testing on compilers is only tentative proof, you have to read the standard to get "real" proof. It's not allowable C++; any compiler that accepts it is broken.

Comment: @Ajay: "how STL classes would be able to call default, copy constructors and the destructor?" They use placement `new` (via their allocator's `construct` function) to construct objects in preallocated blocks of memory.

Comment: @Mike, Okay they won't call COPY CONSTRUCTOR. My mistake on that. But STL containers DO call assignment-operator, default-constructor and the destructor. You pass type `T` the them, and `T t1;` would call the def-CTOR, `T t2; t2=t1;` would call assignment operator, `t1.T::~T()` would call DTOR. Don't browse the code, just make any of them private and see.

Comment: @Ajay: indeed, containers are allowed use all those things, but that has nothing to do with the discussion of whether a copy-constructor could ever receive `this` as its argument. As several people have said, it can't, because there's no valid way to call a constructor on an already-constructed object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly from your comments on Johannes' answer, you only want to copy one generation of children?  Make another constructor, e.g.

```
class X
{
public:
    X(const X& other)
        :left_(0), right_(0)
    {
        left_ = new X(*other.left_, 1);
    }

    X(const X& other, unsigned howDeep)
        :left_(0), right_(0)
    {
        if(howDeep == 0)
            return;
        left_ = new X(*other.left_, howDeep - 1);
    }
private:
    X* left_;
    X* right_;    
};
```

Comment: Wow, recursion with copy constructors!

Answer (score 4):

You have an infinitely large tree, as it looks like both your `left_` and `right_` pointers always point to another `X`? What else do you expect from copying such a large tree than always descending into another subtree?

You want to have a stop condition, like

```
    X::X(const X& pattern)
    :left_(0), right_(0)
    {
        if(pattern.left_)
            left_ = new X(*pattern.left_);//this is the line
        /* ... */
    }
```

Comment: @Johan yes, that is a solution but only if you want copy everything. I (and I am sorry for not mention that, was bit in a hurry) need to copy just "one next to" if you know what I mean

Comment: @Andre wouldn't they be equal if you pass this obj as a param to a ctor?

Comment: what doesn't make sense to you Johann?